# How to run python bottle on port 80?

Tags: python, http, webserver, bottle

When trying to run python bottle on port 80 I get the following:

```
socket.error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forb
idden by its access permissions
```

My goal is to run the web server on port 80 so the url's will be nice and tidy without any need to specify the port 
for example:

```
http://localhost/doSomething
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:8080/doSomething
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly as the error says. You need to have permissions to run something on the 80th port, normal user cannot do it. You can execute the bottle webapp as root (or maybe www-data) and it should be fine as long as the port is free.

But taking security (and stability) into consideration you should look at different ways of deployment, for example nginx together with gunicorn.

- [Gunicorn Docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/)
- [Nginx Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/)

Answer (score 2):

- Check your system's firewall setting.
- Check whether another application already use port 80 using following commands:

  - On unix: `netstat -an | grep :80`
  - On Windows: `netstat -an | findstr :80`

---

According to [**Windows Sockets Error Codes**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **WSAEACCES** 10013
>
> Permission denied.
>
> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its
>   access permissions. An example is using a broadcast address for sendto
>   without broadcast permission being set using setsockopt(SO_BROADCAST).
>   Another possible reason for the WSAEACCES error is that when the bind
>   function is called (on Windows NT 4.0 with SP4 and later), another
>   application, service, or kernel mode driver is bound to the same
>   address with exclusive access. Such exclusive access is a new feature
>   of Windows NT 4.0 with SP4 and later, and is implemented by using the
>   SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE option.

Comment: if i'm not worng if the port is already used, the system says "port already opened"

Comment: @FoxMaSk, I added a text from MSDN.

Comment: that what i found by searching this error, typically linked to windows os

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes dont need to want install nginx, python with gunicorn is a viable alternative with supervisor but you need to make lot of tricks for working

i assume you know install supervisor, and later install again requirements

```
pip3 install virtualenv
mkdir /home/user/.envpython
virtualenv /home/user/.envpython/bin/activate
source /home/user/.envpython/bin/activate
cd /home/user/python-path/
pip3 install -r requirements
```

create a supervisor file like that

```
nano /etc/supervisord.d/python-file.conf
```

and edit with this example, edit the program that you need, remember the python3 run in other ports > 1024

```
;example with path python supervisor in background
[program:python]
environment=HOME="/home/user",USER="user"
user=user
directory = /home/user/python-path
command = python3 /home/user/python-path/main.py

priority = 900
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stopsignal = TERM

;redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile = /home/user/.main-python-stdout.log
stderr_logfile = /home/user/.main-python-stderr.log

;example with path python gunicorn supervisor and port 80
[program:gunicorn]
;environment=HOME="/home/user",USER="user"
;user=user
directory = /home/user/python-path
command = bash /home/user/.scripts/supervisor-initiate.sh

priority = 900
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stopsignal = TERM

;redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile = /home/user/.main-python-stdout.log
stderr_logfile = /home/user/.main-python-stderr.log
```

and create the file

```
nano /home/user/.scripts/supervisor-initiate.sh
```

with the following content

```
source /home/user/.envpython/bin/activate
cd /home/user/python-path
gunicorn -w 1 -t 120 -b 0.0.0.0:80 main:app
```

i assume you file in python is called main and you initiate the app with flask or django that called "app"

only restart supervisord process

```
systemctl restart supervisord
```

and you have the app with gunicorn in the port 80, i post because i find for a very long time for this solution

Waiting works for anyone